# Warning C6386: Buffer overrun while writing data (c) Exception thrown at 0x00F622D9

Tags: c

My C code has been having an issue in my lab creating matrices and I for the life of me cannot figure out why. The main function and create function run fine, but in my initialize an error appears about the incorrect space being allocated. Can someone please explain to me how I can fix this?

my structure definition:

```
typedef struct matrix {
    double** x;
    int rows;
    int cols;
} matrix;
```

my initialization:

```
struct matrix initM(const int M, const int N, double cst) {
    matrix data;
    data.x = (double**)malloc(M * N * sizeof(double));
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
        data.x[i] = (double *)malloc(M*sizeof(double));
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            data.x[j][i] = cst;
        }
    }
    data.rows = M;
    data.cols = N;

    return data;
}
```

my create function:

```
int createM(matrix* data, int *counter) {
    int M, N;
    double cst;

    printf("Rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &M);
    printf("Columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    printf("Constant: ");
    scanf("%lf", &cst);

    *data = initM(M, N, cst);
    printf("Matrix stored as matrix %d\n", (*counter) + 1);
    ++(*counter);
}
```

the picture below are the requirements which is why I was confused about malloc as float matrix[M][N]

[image]

Comment: `data.x` should be set to point to an array of `N` (or maybe `M`) `double *`s, not an array of `N*M` `double`.  Also, both your loops on `i,j` go up to `M` but presumably one of them should be `N`.

Comment: Your matrix allocations and dimensions look a bit mixed up. `malloc(M * N * sizeof(double))` should be `malloc(M * sizeof(double *))` and `data.x[i] = (double *)malloc(*sizeof(double));` should be `data.x[i] = (double *)malloc(N*sizeof(double));` and `for (j = 0; j < M; j++)` should be `for (j = 0; j < N; j++)`

Comment: Cec, Better to use `data.x = malloc(sizeof *data.x * M * N);` than `data.x = (double**)malloc(M * N * sizeof(double));`.

Comment: Cec, Why code `M` in `data.x[i] = (double *)malloc(M*sizeof(double));  for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {`?

Comment: It's supposed to be two dimensional array and the directions said to "create matrix float matrix[M*N] which i didn't really understand but I didn't ask

Comment: This helped so much thank you all!